# Can I use a full word to split on a string?

Tags: perl, split

This may be a simpleton question. I have a string that is consistent with the content. It will contain the word `"IMAGE"`. I want to be able to split on this word so I get the content after the word. I tried:

```
my @sname = split('IMAGE', $fshare);
```

`$fshare` contains a string such as `'\\Disk\InfoIMAGEstuff'`. I want the `'stuff'` part.

Comment: The first argument to split is a regex pattern, not a string. `my ($before, $after) = split(/IMAGE/, $fshare, 2)` should work fine (the limit prevents it from splitting into more than 2 strings).

Comment: The only caveat is if your split pattern contains regex metacharacters, you need to put `\Q` at the beginning to quotemeta it if you want it used literally. But `IMAGE` does not.

Comment: If you plainly want everything after `IMAGE`, no questions asked, I'd recommend a regex in this case; the `split` returns both what's before and after (all occurrences of) the pattern. Then you'd need to think of how many `IMAGE` substrings there may be and which one you want. For everything after the first one, `my ($rest) = $fshare =~ /IMAGE(.*)/;`

Comment: Thanks Grinnz, that should do the job,

Comment: Thanks zdim. I will try that also to get a better understanding of regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to split is a regex pattern, not a string. You can pass a third argument as a limit to prevent it from splitting into more than 2 strings (more than once).

```
my ($before, $after) = split /IMAGE/, $fshare, 2;
```

If the string you want to split on contains regex metacharacters, you will want to use [\Q](https://perldoc.pl/functions/quotemeta) so the string is interpreted literally.

```
my ($before, $after) = split /\Qfoo.bar/, $fshare, 2;
```

If you only care about what is after the delimiter, you can use a simple [regex capture](https://perldoc.pl/perlretut#Extracting-matches) to retrieve this.

```
my ($after) = $fshare =~ m/IMAGE(.*)/s;
```

The `/s` modifier allows `.` to additionally match newlines.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get the part after the string, you could avoid using `split` (and the RegEx engine) all together and use string ops instead.

```
my $string = '\\Disk\InfoIMAGEstuff';
my $delim  = 'IMAGE';
my $post   = substr($string, index($string, $delim) + length($delim));
```

It's not super pretty, but it benchmarks twice as fast as using `split`. Even though we are calling 3 functions (`substr`, `index`, and `length`), string ops like these are incredibly fast.

In this example, `index` matches the first occurrence of `$delim`. If you want to match the last occurrence, use `rindex` instead.